# Minimum number of polygonal lines connecting points in an annulus.

Tags: cv.complex-variables

It is obvious that an open annulus in the complex plane: $S = a < |z| < b$ is connected. That is, each pair of point $z_1$ and $z_2$ in it can be joined by a polygonal line.

What is the minimum number of polygonal lines connecting $z_1$ and $z_2$ in S?

Comment: It seems clear that the maximum should be achieved when the two points are $-a$ and $a$. Then some geometry of tangent lines should get to an answer. Did you try this approach?

Comment: Is "minimal number of polygonal lines" = "the minimal number of straight-line segments in a line joining the two points"?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a regular $n$-polygon for which the circumradius is equal $b$ and the aposthem is smaller than a. Then what is the smallest $n$ such that
$$ b \cos(\pi/n)  \leq a $$
and hence 
$$ n \geq \frac{\pi}{\arccos(a/b)} $$

Comment: Why is the polygon regular?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misinterpreting the question, but if you mean: What is the maximum, over all $z_1$
and $z_2$, of the minimum number of segments in a polygonal line connecting $z_1$ to $z_2$,
then it seems there is no bound: A very thin annulus needs an aribitrarily large number of segments
to connect diametrically opposed points.

[image: annulus]

Comment: I took the problem to be, bound the number of segments in terms of $a$ and $b$. 

Comment: @Gerry: Your interpretation makes sense, in which case my figure supports André's answer.

Comment: @Joseph, I see your figure and Andre's answer as expansions of my comment on the original question, a comment which I hoped OP would pick up on and develop himself into something like Andre's answer. But OP seems to have left the room. 